# How to set Schema in `redshift_connector`?

Tags: python, amazon-redshift

I am using redshift_connector - [Amazon Redshift connector for Python >= 3.5](https://github.com/aws/amazon-redshift-python-driver)

How to set the *schema* while running code from python.

```
import redshift_connector

# Connects to Redshift cluster using AWS credentials
conn = redshift_connector.connect(
    host='examplecluster.abc123xyz789.us-west-1.redshift.amazonaws.com',
    database='dev',
    user='awsuser',
    password='my_password'
 )

cursor = conn.cursor()
cursor.execute("create awesome_schema.Temp table book(bookname varchar,author‎ varchar)")

cursor.execute("select * from awesome_schema.book")
```

That's how I am setting schema to `awesome_schema` in the code.

But this is super tedious and not configurable. Of course, I can manipulate the string and set schema.

But I am wondering is there a better way to set `Schema`?

I have already looked into the https://github.com/aws/amazon-redshift-python-driver repo but have not found many suitable examples.